# Loading SNOMED ontology into GraphDB

Tags: graphdb, snomed-ct

Has any had success in loading the SNOMED ontology into GraphDB (desktop V10.4.1 on MacOSX)?

I have converted the original source into turtle format (result is 1.1GB and 10 million lines).

The load process takes forever...and does not seem to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have successfully loaded SNOMED CT into GraphDB on a Mac. If the load process is taking forever then GraphDB may be running low on memory.

I documented the steps I used, including increasing the memory available to GraphDB, here: [Converting SNOMED CT to RDF for GraphDB import](https://github.com/IHTSDO/snomed-owl-toolkit/issues/64#issuecomment-1088422536)

Comment: Can you say what reasoning you used? And I guess no instance data?

Comment: I loaded the axioms, stated form, of SNOMED CT into Protégé and exported that as RDF. Perhaps I should have run a reasoner first? We at SNOMED International use ELK version 0.4.3. Correct, no instance data.

Comment: If you've already done the reasoning using ELK then you shouldn't need reasoning in GraphDB. The default is `owl-horst` which is not quite light-weight